# Save object details

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I use a user object (attribute email, display name, permissions…) on several areas. 
Is it possible to load the user details after the login and save it for the complete live time? 
Or I need to reload the user information from Azure database by each load a new page?

Regards
Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is hard to understand, but if you're asking if you need to query the user with each request, the answer is yes. HTTP is a stateless protocol. Each request that is made is as if nothing happened before or since. In other words, the fact that you queried something from your database on a previous request has no bearing whatsoever on the current request.

You *can* use sessions to fake state, by persisting a serialized representation of the object in the session store. However, the session store will be a database, itself, if you're doing it right, so it still would involve a query. The only benefit would be that the query would be simplistic. In other words, there's some value of persisting to the session or some other form of cache if your original query was extremely complex and/or time-consuming to complete. However, querying a row by id is about as simplistic as a query can get, so that's not the situation here.

Long and short, if you need the user again, just query it again.